# This error is saying that 'points' is not defined. How would you fix this?

Tags: python

Okay so when I test this, it gives me the error stating that 'points' is not defined. I don't know how to fix this, can I get some help please?
p.s. The code is not totally finished. I still have to print out the other points too, but I want to fix this error beforehand.

> line 43, in main print(distance(points[0]) + "         " +
>   distance(points[1])) NameError: name 'points' is not defined

```
from math import *

def distance():
    points = [(6, 5.7), (-9, 0)]
    set1 = points[0]
    set2 = points[1]
    x1 = set1[0]
    y1 = set1[1]
    x2 = set2[0]
    y2 = set2[1]

    distance = sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 + y2)**2)
    return distance

def secondDistance():
    points = [(0, 0), (4, 1)]
    set1 = points[0]
    set2 = points[1]
    x1 = set1[0]
    y1 = set1[1]
    x2 = set2[0]
    y2 = set2[1]

    distance = sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 + y2)**2)
    return distance

def thirdDistance():
    points = [(100, -100), (500, 300)]
    set1 = points[0]
    set2 = points[1]
    x1 = set1[0]
    y1 = set1[1]
    x2 = set2[0]
    y2 = set2[1]

    distance = sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 + y2)**2)
    return distance

def main():
    print("Original List")
    print("Set 1           Set 2")
    print(distance(points[0]) + "         " + distance(points[1]))
    print(distance())
    print(secondDistance())
    print(thirdDistance())
main()
```

Comment: `points` is a variable local to the functions they are defined in, So are not accessible outside those functions. You also have a different `points` variable in each function, which one did you want to refer to in `main`? Those 3 functions are all the same bar the `points` variable, perhaps you should pass `points` in as an argument, to avoid duplication and also to allow access to the values from `main`.

Comment: move each of the `points` variable definition from the first line of each function into the `main()` method, into a line before each corresponding method is called.

Comment: `distance` doesn't even take any arguments. What were you trying to do with `print(distance(points[0]) + "         " + distance(points[1]))`? We can't tell you how to do it right if you don't tell us what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have three functions to do exactly the same thing?  This entirely defeats the purpose of a function: reuse.  Try this: a single function that takes the pair of points as its argument.  List the three points in your main program, and iterate through the list of points.

```
from math import sqrt

def distance(points):
    p1, p2 = points
    print "  points:", p1, p2
    x1, y1 = p1
    x2, y2 = p2
    print "  coords:", x1, y1, x2, y2
    distance = sqrt((x1 - x2)**2 + (y1 + y2)**2)
    return distance

point_list = [
    [(6, 5.7), (-9, 0)],
    [(0, 0), (4, 1)],
    [(100, -100), (500, 300)]
]

for point_pair in point_list:
    print distance(point_pair)
```

Output:

```
  points: (6, 5.7000000000000002) (-9, 0)
  coords: 6 5.7 -9 0
16.0464949444
  points: (0, 0) (4, 1)
  coords: 0 0 4 1
4.12310562562
  points: (100, -100) (500, 300)
  coords: 100 -100 500 300
447.2135955
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that in the function `main`, there is no variable named `points`. In each of your distance functions, you define a variable named `points`, but that variable is not visible from inside the `main` function.

Also, you should note that your distance functions don't take any arguments, so `distance(points[0])` wouldn't work, even if `points` were defined inside `main`.

Finally, things like this are not necessary:

```
set1 = points[0]
x1 = set1[0]
```

You can simply write:

```
x1 = points[0][0]
```

What you should do is reorganize your code to make `distance` a function that takes two points, and returns a distance between them. Then, inside `main`, define the points you want to get distances between, and call `distance` on them:

```
from math import sqrt

def distance(point0, point1):
    dx = point0[0] - point1[0]
    dy = point0[1] - point1[1]
    return sqrt(dx**2. + dy**2.)

def main():
    p0 = (3., 5.)
    p1 = (1., -2.)
    d = distance(p0, p1)
    print(d)

main()
```